# Optimizing a JavaScript TreeWalker to copy all node except a particular node

Tags: javascript

I have the following the **input DOM**:

```js
var inputNode = document.querySelector('.test');

treeWalker = document.createTreeWalker(
  inputNode, NodeFilter.SHOW_ALL, null, false
);
currentNode = treeWalker.nextNode();

var tempDiv = document.createElement('div');
while (currentNode != null) {
  nodeType = currentNode.nodeType;
  if (
    currentNode.tagName && currentNode.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'span' &&
    currentNode.dataset && currentNode.dataset.element && currentNode.dataset.element === "retain"
  ) {
    tempDiv.appendChild(currentNode.cloneNode(true));
    currentNode = treeWalker.nextNode();
  } else if (currentNode.hasChildNodes() === false) {
    tempDiv.appendChild(currentNode.cloneNode(true));
  }
  currentNode = treeWalker.nextNode();
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <font color="#aa533e">
    <font face="Helvetica, serif">
      <font size="1" style="font-size: 8pt">
        <span style="background: #d096ff">Hello <span data-element="retain">World</span></span>
      </font>
    </font>
  </font>
  <font color="#000000">
    <font face="Times New Roman, serif">
      <font size="2" style="font-size: 11pt">This is</font>
    </font>
  </font>
  <b>test</b> example
</div>
```

A
bove is the code I've written, it works well (so far). But I'm not sure the approach I'm doing is the right way.

I want to keep only the `data-element="retain"` node and all other text nodes.

**Expected output:**

```html
<div>
  Hello <span data-element="retain">World</span> This is test example
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think there is a simpler way to doing this with the same API which you used.

It is using the third parameter of the `document.createTreeWalker`, and pass the `acceptNode` function to filter the object what you want to filter.

```js
var nodeIterator = document.createNodeIterator(
  // Node to use as root
  document.getElementById('someId'),

  // Only consider nodes that are text nodes (nodeType 3)
  NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT,

  // Object containing the function to use for the acceptNode method
  // of the NodeFilter
    { acceptNode: function(node) {
      // Logic to determine whether to accept, reject or skip node
      // In this case, only accept nodes that have content
      // other than whitespace
      if ( ! /^\s*$/.test(node.data) ) {
        return NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT;
      }
    }
  },
  false
);

// Show the content of every non-empty text node that is a child of root
var node;

while ((node = nodeIterator.nextNode())) {
  alert(node.data);
}
```

See more information:

1. [TreeWalker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TreeWalker)
2. [NodeFilter/acceptNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeFilter/acceptNode)